# How to remove entityManager

Tags: java, netbeans-7

I am developing an application in java using Netbeans 7.0.
I did something wrong and the following code appeared in iniComponents()----

```
entityManager = java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() ? null : javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(null).createEntityManager();
amcTeamQuery = java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() ? null : entityManager.createQuery("SELECT a FROM AmcTeam a");
amcTeamList = java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() ? java.util.Collections.emptyList() : amcTeamQuery.getResultList();
amcTeamQuery1 = java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() ? null : entityManager.createQuery("SELECT a FROM AmcTeam a");
amcTeamList1 = java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() ? java.util.Collections.emptyList() : amcTeamQuery1.getResultList();---------
```

I tried removing this by opening the source code. But again this code gets generated automatically and some error occurs. Can anyone help me remove this please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you be more explicit where this code is appearing?  What kind of project do you have now (Java desktop, JEE, JavaFX, etc.)?  It's ringing a bell but without the code in front of me I'm not really sure.

Comment: I am developing a Java desktop application. This code appears inside the initComponents(). So I am not able to modify it from the IDE. I tried deleting from the source file. But once I run the project this code reappears and error occurs. Also, two declarations for java.util.list appears in the variable declaration part. ( private java.util.List<amc.AmcTeam> amcTeamList;
    private java.util.List<amc.AmcTeam> amcTeamList1;
    )

Comment: Please update your question with that information.  Also please show a complete list of all files in the project.  I think something got added that you're not looking out.